# Matching the list with column and extract the Match value from the Column

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a problem in matching the list and column of the dataframe and from the match extract the specific match value from the column.

dataset:

```
    address
0   58 Chatham Street, Chatham, New Jersey, 07928
1   3420 W. MacArthur Blvd. Ste. C, Santa Ana, California
2   2016 Chalk Rd, Wake Forest, North Carolina, 27587
```

I have a List contain with state names

```
state = ['New York','New Jersey','California',...]
```

Desire Results

```
    address                                                   State
0   58 Chatham Street, Chatham, New Jersey, 07928             New Jersey
1   3420 W. MacArthur Blvd. Ste. C, Santa Ana, California     California
2   2016 Chalk Rd, Wake Forest, North Carolina, 27587         North Carolina
```

Code i tried

```
for i in state:
    ship_add['state'] = ship_add['address'].str.strip(i)
```

Comment: You can split values into new columns based on commas since the pattern of getting state is not fixed in every rows df['address'].str.split(', ', expand=True)

Comment: What if you try to extract those values that are not all digits at the end? `.str.extract(r'(\w[^,]*)(?:,\s*\d+)?$', expand=False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
state = ['New York','New Jersey','California','North Carolina']

#word boundary
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in state)
#if not necessary words boundary
#pat = '|'.join(state)
df['State'] = df['address'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df)
                                             address           State
0      58 Chatham Street, Chatham, New Jersey, 07928      New Jersey
1  3420 W. MacArthur Blvd. Ste. C, Santa Ana, Cal...      California
2  2016 Chalk Rd, Wake Forest, North Carolina, 27587  North Carolina
```

If matched splitted values:

```
state = ['New York','New Jersey','California','North Carolina']

df1 = df['address'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
df['State'] = df1.where(df1.isin(state)).ffill(1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
                                             address           State
0      58 Chatham Street, Chatham, New Jersey, 07928      New Jersey
1  3420 W. MacArthur Blvd. Ste. C, Santa Ana, Cal...      California
2  2016 Chalk Rd, Wake Forest, North Carolina, 27587  North Carolina
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, It gives me Nan values

Comment: Hi @jezrael. Its my bad. I had a problem with the dataset due to that I face Nan. Yes, now its working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
state = ['New York','New Jersey','California','North Carolina']
def search_states(df):
    for i in state:
        if i in df['address']:
            df['states'] = i
            break
        else:
            continue
    return df
df = df.apply(search_states, axis = 1)
```

This approach will be faster with larger data also.